# Wait for a command to terminate

Tags: batch-file

I'm currently working on a batch file that should download files via their URL and them run formatting script on them however I don't know how to to delay the batch-file during downloading, however since it's a direct download the window doesn't stay open.
here's where I'm at :

```
START "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" https://www.oui.oui.fr/oui
MOVE C:\\Users\\*\\downloads\\*.csv %~dp0
EXIT
```

I would like to wait for the first line to finish before continuing.
Thanks for your consideration

Comment: do you want to wait for the first line to complete?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Yes, that's it.

Comment: `start /wait`. The command is "finished" when you close the browser.

Comment: Then simply do `start "" /wait "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" https://www.oui.oui.fr/oui`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From cmdline (`cmd.exe`) run `start /?` and you will find some help. There is a specific line in the help file for the `/wait` switch which reads:

```
WAIT        Start application and wait for it to terminate.
```

So simply start chrome with the `/wait` switch:

```
Start /wait "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" https://www.oui.oui.fr/oui
```

As per your comment, the above will not work. It is probably best to test if the file exists, chrome will have a .crdownload extension when still downloading. So let's test that the `*.csv.crdownload` does not exist.

```
start /wait "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" https://www.oui.oui.fr/oui
:hold
timeout 5
if /i not exist *.csv.crdownload (MOVE "C:\\Users\\*\\downloads\\*.csv" %~dp0) else ( goto :hold)
exit
```

Comment: This line does not seem to work this could be because I use download links that close the window automaticly

Comment: Does the browser close directly after launch?

Comment: Yes it does. ^^"

Comment: It is always one file

Comment: See the edit please. let's also cleanup some comments.

Comment: Just a last question, what does /i does in that case ?

Comment: `/i` is to match the string case insensitive. so it will match `csv.download` and `CSV.DoWnlOAD` etc.